# Ubuntu 20.04 battery is charged but shows empty

Tags: battery

I just installed ubuntu 20.04 on my asus laptop and have been having battery issues ever since.

The lights on the laptop show that the battery is fully charged while Ubuntu says it's critically low and shuts down if I unplug the power supply. Also, as the power cord is plugged in the battery shows critically low and is not charging.

I don't know what to do.

Please, help!

Comment: "The lights on the laptop show that the battery is fully charged"   That is probably not a correct assumption: the lights show that the battery is at maximum charge not at 100% max capacity it originally was. (Energy When Full versus  Energy (Design)) Please add the commands and results of the following commands `upower -e` and `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_{xxx}` Change {xxx} to what the 1st command showed. (could be BAT1, or CMB0)

Comment: and look at energy-full and  energy-full-design If there is a BIG gap between the 2 you probably need to replace the battery. Add a comment if you need more help :)

Comment: Thanks! Will do as you laid out and will post my results.

Comment: Ok...followed your instructions. Here's the gap...energy-full:         35.805 Wh
    energy-full-design:  46.238 Wh

Comment: Is that a big gap?

Comment: Yes to me it is :P Mine has energy-full:   78,22 Wh energy-full-design:  80 Wh =97%.  On a machine that is 9 months old. Yours is on 76%. How old is it?  I would keep an eye on the numbers: if they drop more within a week I would get a new battery.

Comment: I  bought a new battery and put it in…same problem!